# Python PyQt5 вывод текста в QPainter

Tags: python, python-3.x, qt, многопоточность, pyqt5

Всем привет. есть пример кода.

```
from tkinter import *
import os
import time
import cv2
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
import threading
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
y = 10
faces = 0


face_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier(r'haarcascade\haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml')
eye_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier(r'haarcascade\haarcascade_eye.xml')



root = Tk()
root.title('test')
root.geometry('850x600+500+10')
root.minsize(850, 600)

root.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
root.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

canvas = Canvas(root, highlightthickness=0, bg='black')
canvas.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")

canvas.grid_rowconfigure(1, weight=1)
canvas.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

cam = Label(canvas, width=50, height=20)
cam.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky="ne")
cam.grid_propagate(False)


def поиск_лиц(frame):
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    faces = face_cascade.detectMultiScale(gray, 1.2, 3)
    y2 = 10
    col = 0
    name = ['face_names', 'face_names2', 'face_names3', 'face_names4', 'face_names5']
    for (x, y, w, h), name in zip(faces, name):
        cv2.rectangle(frame, (x, y), (x+w, y+h), (0, col, 255), 2)

        cv2.rectangle(frame, (10, y2), (200, y2+30), (0, col, 255), cv2.FILLED)
        font = cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_DUPLEX
        cv2.line(frame, (x, y), (200, y2 + 30), (0, col, 255), 2)
        cv2.putText(frame, name, (10 + 6, y2+25), font, 0.8, (255-col, 255-col, 255-col), 1)
        y2 += 40
        col += 50

    return frame, faces




def video_loop():
    global faces
    """ Get frame from the video stream and show it in Tkinter """
    ok, frame = cap.read()
    if ok:
        frame = cv2.flip(frame, 1)
        frame = поиск_лиц(frame)
        faces = len(frame[1])

        img = Image.fromarray(frame[0])
        img = img.resize((420,310), Image.ANTIALIAS)
        imgtk = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image=img)
        cam.imgtk = imgtk
        cam.configure(image=imgtk, width=400, height=300)
    root.after(30, video_loop)



def printer():
    global y

    while True:
        if y < 260:
            y += 20

        else:
            for i in range(0, 20):
                canvas.move("centr_canvas", 0, -1)
                root.update()

        canvas.create_text(10, y, font=("Purisa", 10),
                                 text='Test print - found {0} persons'.format(faces),
                                 anchor="nw", fill='#FFFFFF', tag="centr_canvas")

        time.sleep(1)
        root.update()


threading.Thread(target=video_loop).start()
threading.Thread(target=printer).start()

root.mainloop()
```

И у меня есть два вопроса.

Почему анимация текста через некоторое время начинает тормозить?

И главный вопрос, как сделать что-то подобное на PyQt5 ?

В PyQt я полный ноль.
Использую Python 3.6

Про главный вопрос , вот пример кода без камеры.

```
from tkinter import *
import os
import time
import threading
y = 10
r = 0


root = Tk()
root.title('test')
root.geometry('850x600+500+10')
root.minsize(850, 600)

root.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
root.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

canvas = Canvas(root, highlightthickness=0, bg='black')
canvas.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")




def printer():
    global y, r

    while True:
        r += 1
        if y < 260:
            y += 20

        else:
            for i in range(0, 20):
                canvas.move("centr_canvas", 0, -1)
                root.update()

        canvas.create_text(10, y, font=("Purisa", 10),
                                 text='Test print - '+ str(r),
                                 anchor="nw", fill='#FFFFFF', tag="centr_canvas")

        time.sleep(1)
        root.update()



threading.Thread(target=printer).start()

root.mainloop()
```

надеюсь это поможет.

Comment: Вопросы лучше разделять по смыслу, т.е. один вопрос мог быть про рисование в tk, а другой про тот как сделать то же самое в pyqt. Вот допустим я хорошо знаю pyqt, рисование на нем уже делал и хотел вам помочь с главным вопросом, но как мне это сделать, если ваш код при запуске у меня не будет работать (нет нужных файлов)? :) Да и даже скриншота примера нет. А так, на Qt, рисование у вас получится (гуглите QPainter), но меня смущает использование `cv2` -- оно останется для поиска лиц, чтобы получить точки/фигуры, но рисование будет на Qt, тогда должно получиться

Comment: gil9red , я не совсем понял про какие вы файлы говорите , но на всякий случай кинул пример кода без камеры, и именно со второго кода надо перенести в PyQt приложение  .

Comment: т.е. вам достаточно показать пример рисования как в коде `Про главный вопрос , вот пример кода без камеры.`?

Comment: всё верно. Нужно чтобы в PyQt выполнялось тоже самое что и во втором коде на tk.

Comment: `Почему анимация текста через некоторое время начинает тормозить?` скорее всего дело в `canvas.create_text` -- он накапливает текст и отрисовывает его, тормозит из-за накопленного объема данных и/или из-за того что весь накопленный текст пытается нарисовать (мое предположение)

Answer (score 2):

Практически строка в строку переписанный код на `Qt`:

```
import time
import threading

from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QGraphicsScene, QGraphicsView
from PyQt5.QtGui import QFont
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt


app = QApplication([])

mw = QMainWindow()
mw.setWindowTitle('test')
mw.resize(500, 500)

scene = QGraphicsScene()
scene.setBackgroundBrush(Qt.black)

view = QGraphicsView()
view.setScene(scene)

# Расположение сцены в левом верхнем углу, по умолчанию она по центру
view.setAlignment(Qt.AlignLeft | Qt.AlignTop)

# Ограничение размера виджета
# view.setFixedHeight(300)

mw.setCentralWidget(view)


y = 10
r = 0


def printer():
    global y, r

    while True:
        r += 1
        y += 20

        item = scene.addText('Test print - ' + str(r), font=QFont('Purisa', 10))
        item.setPos(10, y)
        item.setDefaultTextColor(Qt.white)

        time.sleep(1)

        # Скроллинг вниз
        view.verticalScrollBar().setValue(view.verticalScrollBar().maximum())


# daemon=True нужен чтобы при завершении главного потока, этот поток тоже завершался
thread = threading.Thread(target=printer, daemon=True)
thread.start()

mw.show()

app.exec()
```

Скриншот:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

Небольшой ликбез: [QGraphicsScene](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgraphicsscene.html) хранит данные, т.е. является моделью, а [QGraphicsView](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgraphicsview.html) данные отрисовывает. Когда на сцену добавляется какой-нибудь элемент, она сообщает об этом вью, и та отрисовывает.

---

**PS.** Изначально хотел делать через [QPainter](http://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/QPainter.html), но т.к. переписывался код с [tk.Canvas](http://www.effbot.org/tkinterbook/canvas.htm), но мне показалось что тут лучше подойдет [QGraphicsScene](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgraphicsscene.html) и [QGraphicsView](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgraphicsview.html).

**PPS.** В текущей реализации мне не нравится способ работы с виджетом – обращение к виджету из побочного потока идея плохая. Каноничный вариант работы – создание потока с тем циклом и отправка сигнала из того побочного потока в главный поток, например передача текущих значений `y` и `r`, а в главном потоке создавался бы элемент и смещался ползунок.

**PPPS.** Довольно непросто было с сценой, скорее дело привычки, ибо с ней почти не работал (в отличии от того же `QPainter`'а)

Comment: gil9red - спасибо вам за даное решение , но я надеялся что вы покажете как сделать это именно на QPainter'e , так как в дальнейшем я буду работать только с виджетом QPainter.

Comment: @РоманПочинок, наследуете QWidget, в методе paintEvent вызываете QPainter и рисуете им. Однако, пеинтер вызывается на события перерисовки виджета, т.е. он не запоминает что нужно рисовать и полностью перерисовывает всё, поэтому нужно где-то помнить эту информацию -- например в списке ([(y, r), (y + 20, r)]). Мои примеры: https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/blob/14a4b4771be32df180b7ba3e5050804de3c13a9f/qt__pyqt__pyside__pyqode/draw__ellipse_board__decrease/main.py#L16 и https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/blob/149b094bf3e050bd1a7ca0d3db3303974eabb9ca/tic_tac_toe__example.py#L100

Comment: Спасибо за информацию, буду разбираться :-(